# Convert numpy.recarray to dict assigning entries to their fundamental types for passing to fastAPI

Tags: python, json, numpy, fastapi

to pass the content of this recarray to fastAPI:

```
import numpy


rec_array =  numpy.recarray(shape = (1, ), 
                            dtype = [('col_a', 'O'), 
                                     ('col_b', '<f8'), 
                                     ('col_c', '<i8')])
rec_array['col_a'][0]  = '0'
rec_array['col_b'][0]  = 1.0
rec_array['col_c'][0]  = 128
```

This version works:

```
{'col_a':[str(rec_array['col_a'][0])], 
 'col_b':[float(rec_array['col_b'][0])], 
 'col_c':[int(rec_array['col_c'][0])]}
```

but this one does **not**:

```
{name:[rec_array[name][0]] for name in rec_array.dtype.names}
```

I would like to understand why. Here is the error trace I get from fastAPI, under windows:

```
  File "C:\Users\xor\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\fastapi\encoders.py", line 158, in json
able_encoder
    raise ValueError(errors)
ValueError: [TypeError("'numpy.int64' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute'
)]
```

Comment: could you please add the fastapi part of the code? How do you pass it to fast-api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you're facing is because of the int64 (`<i8`) type. In your first code snippet, you're explicitly casting it to a regular int:

```
'col_c':[int(rec_array['col_c'][0])]
         ===
```

While in the second, it stays a `numpy.int64`:

```
d = {name:[rec_array[name][0]] for name in rec_array.dtype.names}
type(d["col_c"][0])
===> numpy.int64
```

To solve this, you can do the following:

```
def make_int(x):
    if isinstance(x, np.int64):
        return int(x)
    return x

{name:[make_int(rec_array[name][0])] for name in rec_array.dtype.names}
```

This results in a duct you can send to fast API.